# Allow crawlers to pass link juice from similar and duplicated user created pages

Tags: htaccess, web-crawlers, robots.txt, backlinks

My users commonly create new pages with similar/duplicate content.  For example:

- `http://example.com/post?123`
- `http://example.com/post?456`

I've therefore disallowed these pages in the *robots.txt* file.

But my users also created a lot of backlinks to these pages.

Is there any effective way for me to pass the link juice or redirect the crawler from these pages too the start page?

Comment: What's the "start page"? eg. `http://example.com/<post-slug>`? So, basically you just want to get rid of the query string?

Comment: Yes, the startpage would be http://example.com/. So a user should see the content of "http://example.com/post?123" whilst the crawler or link juice is passed to http://example.com/.

Comment: Are the pages duplicate *of* the home page of the site?   It would only be appropriate to mark the content as duplicate if it actually is so.

Comment: You can't show one URL to users and show another (unrelated) URL to search engines ("cloaking" - black hat SEO) OR attribute "link juice" to that other URL (`rel="canonical"` can only be used on same/similar pages) - which is what you seem to be wanting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Juice only flows in and from pages that are indexable.*

- There is no secret squirrel code to change this outcome.

*Some people and some sites may suggest to use:*

- `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW">`

The follow command used within the meta will only inform Google to follow links to discover new pages, it does not imply to pass juice.

*Selectively Select Quality Profiles*

If you want to be rewarded then you can selectively enable index on those pages that are considered high quality.

*Not all links are born equal*

You should also note that even if the profile page is considered unique content, the backlinks created for this page may have a:

- Big Effect
- Some Effect
- Negative Effect
- Little Effect
- No Effect

Due to the high volume of backlink abuse over the years Google has fine tuned what type of links it rewards, some links may help the site, some may not at all. If the site has too many incoming backlinks that are not relevant to the topic of the site then you should expect this to work in a negative way.

For example, if your site is about IT hardware reviews, and you have one user profile with a 100 backlinks from various sites about animals and cats, then you should expect that to either have no effect, or a negative effect.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The pages that are created by my users are only useful to themself and their friends/etc. All of these pages have a really low value and that's why I'm blocking them in robots.txt.

As per your reply, would this mean that there isn't any way for me to preserve the linkjuice from backlinks to these low value pages.